# Compactness of a set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $A = \{1/n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\subset\Bbb R.$ I understand that a set must be closed to be compact, and every open set is not compact. I know that $A$ is not closed because $0$ is a limit point, but is not included in $A$.

However, I am not sure how to show that $A$ is open. I don't think $\Bbb R\setminus A$ is closed because it contains $(1, \infty)$ which is not a closed set. Also I can construct a ball centered at $1/2$ with a radius of $1/10$ that doesn't contain any point in $A$.

Should I not be looking at open and closed sets to show $A$ is not compact?

Comment: "Every open set is compact." This is not true. What if the set if both open and closed?

Comment: Written that way, $A$ is just a point.

Comment: Your argument that $A$ complement is not closed is not sufficient. For example, $(-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty)$ clearly has closed complement, but it contains $(0,1)$. Also, a ball of any radius centered at $1/2$ *always* contains a point in $A$, just not necessarily a point distinct from $1/2$.

Comment: The set $A$ you mention is neither open nor closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You should specify the underlying space. For example, if $X=(0,\infty)$, then $A$ is closed.

Comment: sorry the underlying space is the real numbers equipped with the usual metric.

Comment: @egreg I didn't consider that A could be neither open nor closed. If a set is not closed then it cannot be compact right?

Comment: @johndoe In a metric space every compact subset is closed, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

In general, to show a set is compact, you must start with an arbitrary open cover, say $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $A\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$, and prove that from this open cover, there exists a finite subcover. From this general definition, can you find an open cover that doesn't have a finite subcover?

To simplify things significantly, in metric spaces (which $\Bbb R$ is when equipped with the standard topology), this is equivalent to sequential compactness, i.e., for any sequence, there exists a convergent subsequence. Considering elements only in $A$, can you find a sequence which doesn't converge and has no convergent subsequences?

Answer (score 0):

I have a few comments.

You not be trying to show that $A$ is not open, since "not open" does not imply "not compact". You could show that $A$ is not closed, which it's not, and then since all compact sets are closed, this dismisses the possibility that $A$ is compact.

However, if you have been taught compactness in terms of open subcovers, I think you should become comfortable with manipulating this definition directly. If you can practice first with this concrete example, you will start to see how similar arguments might be made when the sets get less easily visualized. Yes, it's a bit painful, but this is a skill you'll need sometime and it's only going to hurt more later :)